# Why Firefox doesn't accept -moz-transition in style?

Tags: javascript, firefox, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set CSS3 transition using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742249/how-to-set-css3-transition-using-javascript)

I try to add an CSS3 transition css property to an element with (native) JavaScript by `style` object of the element, it doesn't work in Firefox but everything is fine in `webkit` browsers. My code:

```
var actor_object = document.querySelectorAll("p");
actor_object.style["-moz-transition-property"] = "all"
```

*Please don't answer that I can do that with `MozTransitionProperty`, I know this but I need to do with `-moz-`.*

Comment: Have you tried `actor_object.style["transition-property"] = "all"`?

Comment: @RenePot Actually I want to build an cross-browser css3 animation. I know that I have the same syntax in `Opera` also, I mean `-o-` and using a common syntax between browsers help me to reduce my code. So, in `Opera` is there any property for that? For example `OTransitionProperty`?

Comment: Because per spec this is not supposed to work.  You can do `actor_object.style.setProperty("-moz-transition-property", "all")`, though.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky I didn't see `setProperty` before, if there's something like that it should work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The stable Firefox release utilizes the W3C-standard non-prefixed `transition-property` CSS property;
2. You have to camelCase CSS properties to apply in JS style;
3. You're trying to set a style to a nodeList, which is what the [DOM QSA method](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) returns. You need to iterate over it.

For a cross-browser solution, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) it'd be as simple as:

```
$('p').css({transitionProperty: "all", transitionDuration: '2s'});​
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lgfk/1/)

If you want a pure JS solution, here's the code for testing supported CSS properties from [`$.cssHooks`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/):

```
function styleSupport(prop) {
    var vendorProp, supportedProp,

        // capitalize first character of the prop to test vendor prefix
        capProp = prop.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + prop.slice(1),
        prefixes = ["Moz", "Webkit", "O", "ms"],
        div = document.createElement("div");

    if (prop in div.style) {

        // browser supports standard CSS property name
        supportedProp = prop;
    } else {

        // otherwise test support for vendor-prefixed property names
        for (var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
            vendorProp = prefixes[i] + capProp;
            if (vendorProp in div.style) {
                supportedProp = vendorProp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // avoid memory leak in IE
    div = null;

    // add property to $.support so it can be accessed elsewhere
    //$.support[prop] = supportedProp;

    return supportedProp;
}
```

Then just use it as such:

```
(function() {
    var transitionProperty = styleSupport("transitionProperty");
    var transitionDuration = styleSupport("transitionDuration");

    var actor_object = document.querySelectorAll("p");
    for (var i = 0, l = actor_object.length; i < l; i++) {
        actor_object[i].style[transitionProperty] = "all";
        actor_object[i].style[transitionDuration] = "2s";
    }
}());
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gypty/1/)