# Smooth color change in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this line of code, which after some event changes color:

```
$('li', this).css('color', '#fff');
```

How to modify it to change colour smoothly, so it takes eg 1 second to fade between the original color and #fff ?

I know it's very easy, but i haven't done it for a while and forgot.
thanks

jsfiddle: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/pftbf/1/)

Comment: does it need to fade back after mouseleave? See this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742249/how-to-set-css3-transition-using-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742249/how-to-set-css3-transition-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution without any additional plugins

**1.** Add this CSS:

```
nav li {
   -webkit-transition:color 1s ease;
   -moz-transition:color 1s ease;
   -o-transition:color 1s ease;
   transition:color 1s ease;
}

.white_color { color:#fff; }
```

#### You can modify *1s* to whatever time value you want, you can also use *ms* if you like.

**2.** Use this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("nav a").mouseenter(function () {
        if ($(this).data('fading')) //EXIT IF WE ARE FADING
        return;
        $('div', this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'height': '45px'
        }, 100);
        $('li', this).addClass('white_color'); // THIS IS THE LINE I'M AFTER - I want the color to change smoothly, not instantly
        $('li', this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'padding-top': '15px'
        }, 200);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        if ($(this).data('fading')) return;
        $('li', this).removeClass('white_color');
        $('div', this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'height': '0px'
        }, 300);

        $('li', this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'padding-top': '65px'
        }, 500);
    });

});
```

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/DanielLisik/pftbf/5/)**

Comment: Awesome. No problem! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS transition:

```
li
{
 color: #000;
 transition: color 1s ease;
}
```

Comment: good and simple, may use this one or the one from DanielLisik. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it from your js:

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transition = "all 2s";
```

Or you can just add it to your CSS:

```
#mydiv {
     transition: all 2s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're the only person who actually answered the question. Did this not exist before??

Comment: Glad that you find it useful!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI comes with a color plugin which allows you to animate colors.

```
$('li', this).animate({
    color: "#fff"
}, 1000);
```

Comment: didn't work for some reason. I've replaced the line, but I've got the answer, although thank you for your help and time.